# count only males from a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['male','female','female','male'],
                      'class':[1,2,3,2],
                      'smoking':[12,22,33,9]
})

   class     sex  smoking
0      1    male       12
1      2  female       22
2      3  female       33
3      2    male        9
```

I am grouping by sex and class:

```
smokers = data.groupby(['sex','class'])['smoking'].agg(sum)

sex     class
female  2        22
        3        33
male    1        12
        2         9
```

Now, I want to count only male smokers.

I know I can do :

```
male_smokers = data[data['sex'] == 'male'].groupby(['sex','class'])['smoking'].agg(sum)
```

but I want to be able to do it like:

```
male_smokers = smokers[smokers['sex'] == 'male'].count()
```

Is that possible?( right now I am receivig 'keyError' sex )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) to take a quick cross section.

```
smokers.loc['male'].sum()
```

or you can be more explicit with [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

```
smokers.xs('male', level='sex').sum()
```

or you could derive directly from `data`

```
data.query('sex == "male"').smoking.sum()
```